# ANDROID - ExpandableListView CustomAdapter child

Tags: android, textview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have a custom ExpandableList.

**list_group.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_layout">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="315dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="290dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:src="@drawable/buton" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
                                android:layout_width="189dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textSize="17dip" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/descripcion"
                        android:textColor="@color/d_gray" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/pixel" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**ListAdapter.java**

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**itm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Fragment {

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//.....
ListView listView = 
                  (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.myListView);
//......

// get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) root.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
// preparing list data
        prepareListData();

listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader,
                listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // Listview Group click listener
        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

// Listview Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                /*
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                 listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 */
            }
        });

        // Listview Group collasped listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                /*
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                 listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 */
            }
        });

        // Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {


// toast
                 /*Toast.makeText( getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                 listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " : " +
                 listDataChild.get( listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                // fin toast


    return false;
            }
        });

    return root;
    }


private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Group1");
        listDataHeader.add("Group2");
        listDataHeader.add("Group3");

// Adding child data
        List<String> G1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        G1.add("Café con leche.... 1.20€");
        G1.add("Manchado.... 1.20€");
        G1.add("Cortado.... 1.20€");


        List<String> G2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        G2.add("item 1 Group 2");
        G2.add("item 2 Group 2");
        G2.add("item 3 Group 2");

        List<String> G3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        G3.add("item 1 Group 3");
        G3.add("item 2 Group 3");
        G3.add("item 3 Group 3");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), G1); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), G2);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), G3);
    }
}
```

okay, that it works perfect.

**My problem!!**

I need two TextView on Child items, I can't implement the second Textview, I don't know how I can add the second TextView on Adapter and later populate manually with a String.

I need do that.

[image: EXPANDABLES]

Comment: add your TextView to `list_item` and you can handle that in `getChildView` on adapter class

Comment: Do you need text views to bi clickable or only to show text?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan,Yes, I've tried to add, but I get no also add in the adapter

Comment: @Zoran I need that when I click the content to appear in EditText, but no action

Comment: what is your mean about "but I get no also add in the adapter"? i don't get you

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I am not able to add the adapter.

Comment: can you explain why you not able?

Comment: I only know how to add a string (Textview), no two strings in the adapter...Thats the problem... =(

Comment: you need change `private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;`. with this line you send one String in each row, but if you send one list of custom class that has 2 String property your problem will be solved

Comment: I understand you, I'll try and I say you again

Comment: @shayanpourvatan finally got to changing the constructor as you told me, thanks.

Comment: Hey have you implemented as shown in the image you added?Can you help me out too?i am also need to implement like it.

Answer (score 0):

Group item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_layout">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Notice that you should change layout orientation to horizontal!

Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
   ViewGroup parent) {     
    LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater)
    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (view == null) {
        view = inf.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
}      
    TextView heading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);

    TextView textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv2);

    return view;
}
```

Here you can set text of both text views and set click listeners

In code:

```
lista.setAdapter(listAdapter);
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 objects (group and child) and use it in adapter.

```
public class Child{
String field1;
String field2;
}

public class Group{
String groupName;
ArrayList<Child> children;
}

public class Adapter extensextends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
ArrayList<Group> groups;
...
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    groupName = groups.get(groupPosition).getGroupName();
    ...
    return convertView;
}
...
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    ...
    chieldField = groups.get(groupPosition).getChildren().get(childPosition).getField();
    ...
    return convertView;
}
...
```